# New here,need help to do"action" just one time

Tags: c#

I have a game code,is working and doing:
*Spawn one animal in a floor tile when tile is accepted,but doing in all accepted tiles.
I want the script do it just one time,here the code:

```
public static void Generate( Rectangle2D region )
    {
        int OakTree = 0x12B9;
        
        for ( int rx = 0; rx < region.Width; ++rx )
        {
            for ( int ry = 0; ry < region.Height; ++ry )
            {
                int vx = rx + region.X;
                int vy = ry + region.Y;

                StaticTile[] tiles = m_Map.Tiles.GetStaticTiles( vx, vy );

                for ( int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; ++i )
                {
                    StaticTile tile = tiles[i];

                    int id = tile.ID;
                    id &= 0x3FFF;
                    int z = tile.Z;

                    if ( IsRock( id ) )
                    {
                        AddAnimalSpawner( vx + 1, vy, z );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to somply it to just one time?I think the problem is `for ( int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; ++i )` .
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to do that only one time , why dont you just quit : for ( int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; ++i ) ???

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to call `AddAnimalSpawner` just one time.

You can simply use the `break` keyword. (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) to return to the outer loops or `return` to exit the `Generate(Rectangle2D region)` Function.

Example:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; ++i )
{
    StaticTile tile = tiles[i];
 
    int id = tile.ID;
    id &= 0x3FFF;
    int z = tile.Z;

    if ( IsRock( id ) )
    {
        AddAnimalSpawner( vx + 1, vy, z );
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
for ( int i = 0; i < tiles.Length; ++i )
{
    StaticTile tile = tiles[i];
 
    int id = tile.ID;
    id &= 0x3FFF;
    int z = tile.Z;

    if ( IsRock( id ) )
    {
        AddAnimalSpawner( vx + 1, vy, z );
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already mentioning: you are getting a collection of tiles (by calling *GetStaticTiles*), and then you add an animal to all of them after verifying that the tile is rock (I guess this has to do with other kind of tiles, like water, where the animal cannot be placed, right?).
In order to do this only one time, you have to break the for look after adding the animal the first time. Here you have several options. One of them is to rewrite your code to better describe what you are doing, but the simpler option you have may be to simply set

```
i = tiles.Length;
```

after calling *AddAnimalSpawner*. This will end the for loop in the next iteration (i.e.: almost immediately) after placing only one animal.

Note that by following the latter method, the outer loop (the one iterating over the regions) will still run. If you don't want that to happen, then you can simply return from the function after adding the only animal.